# How to type into text box generated dynamically

Tags: uipath

I am trying to input data into a dynamically generated text box, but i get the following error:

> Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector: `<webctrl id='dp1545483054838' tag='INPUT' />`

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Go to [www.mockaroo.com](http://www.mockaroo.com)
2. Rename gender to date
3. Click on on Gender under Type and type date in the search and then select Date

This will display two fields from date and to date (dynamically generated). I want change the date in these fields.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, everything is working fine for me

Comment: Confirmed, everything is working just perfectly fine (tested in 2018.3). When working with Chrome or Firefox, make sure that you installed the browser extension (in Design Studio, click Start -> Tools, and then select the appropriate extension).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the comments, I did not have any issues creating a selector to target the `start of range` or `end of range` date fields.

However, in practice, as the form is dynamic, the IDs of the fields will change each time you load the page or introduce a new field so I would not recommend using the ID to select the field.

I dabbled on the page a little to get a feel for it and here are the tidbits that I noticed that might help you out. Without seeing a sample of what you've tried already, this is just a guess at what you are trying to achieve.

---

Ui Explorer generates the following by default

```xml
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Mockaroo - Random Data Generator and API Mocking Tool | JSON / C*' />
<webctrl id='dp1546757265980' tag='INPUT' />
```

1. Check that you are in scope of your selector if you are wanting it to be relative or ensure you are correctly defining a valid hierarchy if using an absolute.
2. Determine a good hierarchy and a few attributes to use that would allow you to specify the field you want while not using attributes or values that are too ambiguous or would never be the same twice

The first thing that I noticed for the start and end date fields is they have a `title` attribute `start of range` and `end of range` values respectively. I think this would be a good start, for myself I ended up including a few more attributes.

```xml
<webctrl tag='INPUT' aaname='start of range' name='*min_date*' parentclass='options' parentid='fields' />
```

Thinking about this a step further, due to the nature of the form you could have multiple option fields that are of the type `Date`, so I anchored my selector to the `date` name field to ensure I was targeting the correct options.

While adding the anchor I noticed that after changing the name field from "gender" to "date" that the HTML code did not update the value to reflect this so it still had the original content

```html
<input placeholder="enter name..." class="column-name form-control" spellcheck="false" type="text" value="gender" name="schema[columns_attributes][4][name]" id="schema_columns_attributes_4_name" uipath_custom_id="1">
```

So instead of being misleading the second time I selected/anchored the Name field, I added a `Find Element` activity and created an output Ui Element variable to pass to the other activities.

[Sample XAML project](https://gist.github.com/codemonkee/1fda9755761f21acc9c2e479c8a7a987)